# mongoDB finding type of value in type of value (genre in specific location)

Tags: mongodb

[This is the example of data field  I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RGGd.png)

I am trying to find all of the 'Greek' restaurants that are in 'MIAMI'

so I submitted to the query

db.location.find({type: 'Greek'},{city: 'MIAMI'})
&
db.location.find({},{'type': 'Greek','city': 'MIAMI'})

but it doesn't filter properly....

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQoei.png)

am I missing an obvious method here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine both terms of the query into a single object:

```
db.location.find({type: 'Greek', city: 'MIAMI'})
```